# Animate Visual Format Language Constraint

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to animate a button from the left side of a container to the right side. The position of this button is defined by the Visual Format Language. (The project is 100% code, no Storyboard issues possible)

**These are my lines for the left side (working):**

```
messageInputContainerView.addSubview(moreButton)
messageInputContainerView.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-3-[v0(35)]-8-[v1][v2(60)]|", views: moreButton, ..., ...)
messageInputContainerView.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: moreButton)
```

**These for the right side + animation (not working):**

```
//I have read that I first have to remove the old constraints in order to apply new ones
moreButton.removeConstraints(moreButton.constraints)

//The only difference here is that the pipe ('|') is on the right side and that I don't care about the two other objects in the container
messageInputContainerView.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:[v0(35)]-3-|", views: moreButton)
messageInputContainerView.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: moreButton)

...

//These lines should be fine, but I include them nontheless
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
      self.moreButton.setTitle("⤇", for: .normal)
      self.messageInputContainerView.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

*If someone is wondering, the 'addConstraintsWithFormat' function looks like this:*

```
extension UIView {

 func addConstraintsWithFormat(format: String, views: UIView...){

    var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()

    for (index, view) in views.enumerated(){
        let key = "v\(index)"
        viewsDictionary[key] = view
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
  }

}
```

I am new to VFL in general, therefore I would really appreciate a helpful answer.

[Here is an image of the container and the *moreButton*. (both at the very bottom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fat6l.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is likely that your constraints are not added to the correct `UIView`s.

You don't have to worry about adding constraints to views if you activate the constraints instead by calling `NSLayoutConstraint(activate:)` with the VFL constraints:

```
extension UIView {

 func addConstraintsWithFormat(format: String, views: UIView...){

    var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()

    for (index, view) in views.enumerated(){
        let key = "v\(index)"
        viewsDictionary[key] = view
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
  }

}
```

---

And then there is this line:

```
//I have read that I first have to remove the old constraints in order to apply new ones
moreButton.removeConstraints(moreButton.constraints)
```

Again, you should be deactivating constraints (setting their `isActive` property to `false`) instead of removing constraints.  The problem with removing constraints like this is that some of the constraints on `moreButton` are stored in the `constraints` array of `moreButton`'s superview.

Keep the constraints you want to deactivate in the future in an array in your VC and then pass the constraints to `NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate()` or set the `isActive` property to `false` for those constraints you wish to deactivate.

---

**Update:**

Your button isn't animating correctly.  That is because it is still contrained to the textField.  To animate your `moreButton`, you need to free it of other constraints that are restricting its position.

First, I would change `addConstraintsWithFormat(format:views:)` to return the constraints it created as `[NSLayoutConstraint]`.  This will allow you to deactivate them later.

```
extension UIView {

 func addConstraintsWithFormat(format: String, views: UIView...) -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {

    var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
    let constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]

    for (index, view) in views.enumerated(){
        let key = "v\(index)"
        viewsDictionary[key] = view
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    return constraints
}
```

Add a property to your viewController:

```
var moreButtonConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
```

Then break up the format `"H:|-3-[v0(35)]-8-[v1][v2(60)]|"` into `"H:|-3-[v0(35)]"` and `"H:|-46-[v1][v2(60)]|"` and activate them separately.  That will separate the constraints for your `moreButton` from the constraints for the other views, allowing you to move the `moreButton` without affecting the other views.

```
messageInputContainerView.addSubview(moreButton)

// save these constraints in a property to be deactivated later
moreButtonConstraints = messageInputContainerView.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-3-[v0(35)]", views: moreButton)

// we don't need to keep these constraints, so assign them to _
_ = messageInputContainerView.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-46-[v1][v2(60)]|", views: ..., ...)
_ = messageInputContainerView.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: moreButton)
```

Then, when it is time to animate:

```
// deactivate the old constraints
NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(moreButtonConstraints)

// add constraints to move the moreButton to the right side
_ = messageInputContainerView.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:[v0(35)]-3-|", views: moreButton)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could not using NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate() (and etc.) cause the problem that the button is only animating to the middle of the screen? After using your better version of 'addConstraintsWithFormat', that is exactly what is happening. Or am I simply using false formats? ("H:[v0(35)]-3-|" and "V:|[v0]|")

Comment: Your second formats look fine, but in your starting formats your moreButton is also constrained to v1.  If you're moving just the moreButton, you should set up two sets of constraints for before and after that don't involve other views besides its container and then deactivate the old ones and activate the new.

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you expect to happen.  It is clear what you want to happen with your moreButton, but what about [v1] and [v2].  Are they supposed to be pushed off the screen as well?

Comment: [v1] is a textfield and [v2] is a button. Their alpha is only animated to 0

Comment: See updated answer.  That should fix your animation problem.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works exactly like I wanted it to work

Comment: Great!  Glad I could help!